# In the Angular 2 Quickstart, what is the purpose of the HeroDetailComponent class's @Input statement?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

In the [multiple compenents](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html) section of the Angular 2 Quickstart tutorial, a component is extracted out of the previous AppComponent in order to make it more reusable and easier to test.

Run the [live example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-3/ts/plnkr.html).

A user can click on a list of `Heroes` and a detailed view will appear below the list.

The components:

1. AppComponent  (List of Heroes)
2. HeroDetailComponent (Display details once a hero is selected)

Both of which import the Hero class:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

In the AppComponent's template, `hero` is a target property:

`<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>`

The `selectedHero` source property is set once a user clicks on a listed hero.

**So far, so good.**

Now, the problem is that I'm not understanding the purpose of `@Input` in the `HeroDetailComponent` class:

```
export class HeroDetailComponent {
  @Input()
  hero: Hero;
}
```

If `@Input()` is omitted, it seems the `hero` property is never set.  How does `@Input()` know where to get the `hero` property from?  Why is this statement required and not just automatically called when a directive has a target property?

It is not obvious to me and it seems that I may be missing the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is the counterpart of `[hero]=` of

```
<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
```

The line above passes `selectedHero` of the current component to the `@Input() hero:hero` of the `<my-hero-detail>` component which I assume is implemented by `HeroDetailComponent` (didn't check the link).

Comment: Is `@Input()
  hero: Hero;` "one piece" of code?  For example, would you ever see something like `hero: Hero` without the `@Input` above it?

Comment: Sure, but then you can't use Angular2 binding like `[hero]="..."` to bind to it. `hero:Hero` is a normal instance property on the `HeroDetailComponent`. The `@Input()` makes it bindable to values from the parent. When it also has `@Output()` heroChange:EventEmitter<Hero> = new EventEmitter<Hero>();` then it can be bound two-way like `[hero]="selectedHero" (heroChange)="selectedHero = $event" or the short form `[(hero)]="selectedHero"`

Answer (score 2):

`@Input` is a **decorator**. This is more of an *TypeScript thing*.

From the **TypeScript Documentation:**

> With the introduction of Classes in TypeScript and ES6, there now exist certain scenarios that require additional features to support annotating or modifying classes and class members. Decorators provide a way to add both annotations and a meta-programming syntax for class declarations and members. Decorators are a stage 1 proposal for JavaScript and are available as an experimental feature of TypeScript.

I recommend you reading the official documentation about this for example [here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md)
It probably will help you understanding the purpose.

As i understand it in the most basic way is that you can think of a `decorator` as a keyword which expects a statement next to it or in the next line / lines. The `decorator` will call a previously defined function with the statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For angular2 specifically, this decorator specifies properties that angular automatically updates during change detection. Non-decorated properties are not automatically updated by angular. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Input-var.html